# what does process.env.MONGODB_URI mean?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication

Does it mean that if I dont provide myURI it will use local mongodb?

```
  MONGODB_URI:
  process.env.MONGODB_URI || myURI
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it looks like this

```
const someConfig = {
   MONGODB_URI:  process.env.MONGODB_URI || myURI
}
```

then `MONGODB_URI` will yield the value of `process.env.MONGODB_URI` if `process.env.MONGODB_URI` resolves to a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value, otherwise it will yield the value of `myURI`.

Comment: So if I push this to a server will it connect to mongo on that server?

Answer (score 0):

the first value that will be evaluated is `process.env.MONGODB_URI` if it has not been set, then the node will evaluate `myURI`. process.env.MONGODB_URI is set by running mongoDB in its workspace (after downloading and installing it first) and myURI by giving it, for example, the url of a cloud database URL MongoDB.